# The anova() function in R to compare a glm() and a glmer() models

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-comparison

I recently tested something regarding the `stats::anova` function in R. 
Assuming `modglm` is a model fitted with the `glm` function and `modglmer` is fitted with the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package on the very same data, the following calls to the `stats::anova` function print different outputs.

This just prints the same output as `anova(modglm)` :

```
anova(modglm,modglmer)
```

However, this prints a comparison of the two models as if they were both `glmer` type models :

```
anova(modglmer,modglm)
```

Apparently the output style of this function depends on the type of the first argument, and I don't get any warnings at all for doing that.

So my question is : does it make **any sense at all** to compare a regular logistic model to a mixed-effects one with this function ?

The two models use the same fixed effects, the only difference is the random effect in the mixed effects one.

Comment: As a general comment about R letting you do surprising things (which doesn't respond to the specifics here) -- rather than trying to stop you shooting yourself in the foot, instead R will quietly try to help you get over any hurdles to shooting yourself in the foot (silent argument recycling for one example) and it will helpfully provide at least half a dozen different ways to do it. It usually won't tell you that you did, and the pain of shooting yourself in the foot may not show up for some time. If you seem to be trying to shoot yourself in the foot R will hand you the right ammunition

Comment: I think I had noticed that, yes. I suppose it's more or less good enough if you know exactly what you are doing but for a beginner like me it's pretty horrid...

Comment: In the first example, the S3 method `stats::anova.glm` is called, in the second example `lme4::anova.merMod` is called. Since `help("glmer")` tells us that "glmer and glm log-likelihoods are consistent" and the method does not throw an error or warning, I assume that you can compare these models using it. I know that you can compare `lmer` and `lm` models.

Comment: But can the comparison be done as you would between two mixed-effects models, are the AIC, BIC and log-likelihood really comparable between them ?